# In pure GR can a black hole spontaneously appear?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, gravitational-waves

In a universe without matter and just gravitation fields, can a black hole spontaneously appear? I would assume it could since such a black hole would evaporate purely into high energy gravitons. The time reverse should also be true.

[Edit: My logic is flawed here. Because the time reversal of a **black hole** is a **white hole** which is not the same!]

So quantum mechanically, I imagine this has to be the case.

Classically, I wonder if there is a solution to GR such that gravitational waves come in from infinity, collapse to form a black hole which lasts a time $T$, then evaporates back into gravitational waves which radiate out to infinity.

Do you know of any such solutions?

Such an exact solution would be interesting to study the metric near the event horizon.

Comment: “Classically … evaporates …” In classical GR, black holes don’t evaporate.

Comment: Also note that if it is planar gravitational waves that solve vacuum wave equation, it cannot interact to form a black hole because of linearity. The closest thing to this is colliding shockwaves (but this has nonzero stress energy), so you cannot have vacuum solutions everywhere unless it is already an eternal black hole solution.

Comment: @Everiana GR is nonlinear.

Comment: @Ghoster exactly. My point is that in the linearized regime that cannot happen, and in the non-linear regime you need (nontrivial) sources.

Comment: @Everiana See https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3880.

Comment: @Ghoster In GR, a stable black hole will not evaporate. However, one could imagine some non-periodic vibrating black hole the slowly emits gravitational waves. Much like a binary black hole system.

Comment: My understanding is that black hole perturbations are highly damped and the hole quickly settles back to a stable state. The hole cannot evaporate away through perturbations. In the case of a non-rotating hole, I don’t think they can decrease its mass in the slightest.

Comment: @Ghoster that may be true for massive black holes. Seems unlikely for mini-black holes.

Comment: In “pure GR” there is no qualitative difference between a small hole and a large hole. There is nothing to set a mass scale. You have a good answer so further discussion is unnecessary.

Comment: @Andrew ah okay I didn't think of Demetrios level construction. You are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q1: Can incoming gravitational waves form a black hole?**

**A: Yes**.

Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3880

**Q2: Can a black hole evaporate in classical GR?**

**A: No,** such a process would violate the area theorem, which states that the area of a black hole horizon can only increase (assuming classical general relativity). Black hole evaporation only occurs in quantum field theory, where the area theorem is violated.

Source:  S. W. Hawking, [Phys. Rev. Lett. 26, 1344 (1971)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.26.1344); [Comm. Math. Phys. 25, 152 (1972)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-25/issue-2/Black-holes-in-general-relativity/cmp/1103857884.full).

Comment: I suppose the time reverse of gravitational waves forming a black hole would be the evaporation of a *white* hole. Thus we could start with a white holes in it which could all evaporate into gravitational waves which could then come together to form black holes. This would be the most "symmetrical" solution.

Comment: @zooby the time reversed solution will violate some energy conditions.

Comment: @MBN probably. also the white holes would have to have existed in the infinite past because they can't be created. Which violates the big bang theory.

Comment: @MBN Are you sure? Most energy conditions are time reversal invariant.